# c# unit test child method calls parameters

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, tdd

Here is my `c#` code.

I'm not sure how I should  verify that `Get` method called with correct parameters.

```
public class ClassToTest
{    
    public IList<Products> GetProducts(string categoryId)
    {
        var items = _service.Get(new Category { id = categoryId, flag = true });
        return items;
    }
}
```

e.g. it was called with `Category` class object with parameter `flag` as `true` and `id` as passed.

Comment: If `service.Get` does not using external resources, don't mock it, setup correct data and check that product of provided category with flag returned. Notice at this moment with in-memory databases you don't need to mock repositories, just data providers.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I can't make comments so I have to write a answer.I hope I have understand it right, what you want to do.

That "new" makes your code hard to test. You should be using the Dependency Inversion principle and give Category object from the outside. You should't make a "new" inside of you method. You are then tied coupled to your Category object implementation. You should program always against the inerfaces and not concret implementations.

You can easily test your method it if you give a Category object as a parameter to the method. This is example.I haven't used interface for the Category class. You can also you for example IFactory interface to give you a concrete implementation of a Category object. It makes testing easier.
In the example is used `NSubstitute`.

```
public IList<Person> GetProducts(Category category)
{
    var items = expressionClass.GetCategory(category);
    return items;
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test2()
{
    var expressionClass = Substitute.For<IExpresionClass>();
    var testClass = new TestClass(expressionClass);
    var category = new Category { flag = true, id = "55" };
    var list = testClass.GetProducts(category);

    expressionClass.Received().GetCategory(Arg.Is(category));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With `FakeItEasy` and dependency inversion principle it's simple as this:

Your class with slight change:

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ClassToTest(IService service) =>
        _service = service;

    public IList<Products> GetProducts(string categoryId) =>
        _service.Get(new Category { id = categoryId, flag = true });
}

public interface IService
{
    IList<Products> Get(Category category);
}
```

Test:

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    string categoryId = "categoryId";
    IService service = A.Fake<IService>();
    ClassToTest sut = new ClassToTest(service);

    // Act
    sut.GetProducts(categoryId);

    // Assert
    A.CallTo(() => service.Get(A<Category>.That.Matches(i => i.id == categoryId && i.flag)))
     .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

or

```
[Test]
public void Test()
{
    // Arrange
    string actualId = null;
    bool? actualFlag = null;

    string categoryId = "categoryId";
    IService service = A.Fake<IService>();
    A.CallTo(() => service.Get(A<Category>.Ignored)).Invokes((Category category) =>
      {
          actualId = category.id;
          actualFlag = category.flag;
      });

    ClassToTest sut = new ClassToTest(service);

    // Act
    sut.GetProducts(categoryId);

    // Assert
    Assert.AreEqual(categoryId, actualId);
    Assert.AreEqual(true, actualFlag);
    // optionaly, because it obviously happened
    A.CallTo(() => service.Get(A<Category>.Ignored))
                          .MustHaveHappened();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct that the Dependency Inversion Principle will help you test this code. I would test this code by mocking out the `_service` in your test class. You can do that with a proper mocking framework or by providing a mock implementation of your service interface. Here is a working example of both options.

## Code Under Test

Here is the code that we are trying to test. A couple things to note:

- We apply the Dependency Inversion Principle by passing the service to the `ClassToTest` constructor.
- I implemented an `Equals` method in the `Category` class. This will make it easier to test this code.

```
public class ClassToTest
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ClassToTest(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IList<Products> GetProducts(string categoryId)
    {
        var items = _service.Get(new Category { id = categoryId, flag = true });
        return items;
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    IList<Products> Get(Category category);
}

public class Category
{
    public string id;
    public bool flag;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Category c = obj as Category;

        if (c == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return c.id == id && c.flag == flag;
    }
}

public class Products
{
}
```

## Test Using Moq

My preferred mocking framework is Moq, but I'm sure others will work just as well for this use case. Here is the test using Moq:

```
[Test]
public void MoqTest()
{
    // Arrange.
    var mockService = new Mock<IService>();
    var target = new ClassToTest(mockService.Object);

    // Act.
    target.GetProducts("test");

    // Assert.
    var expectedCategory = new Category {id = "test", flag = true};
    mockService.Verify(t => t.Get(expectedCategory));
}
```

## Test Without Mocking Framework

You don't need to use a proper mocking framework if you don't want to. You can provide your own mock implementation:

```
public class MockService : IService
{
    public Category CategoryReceived { get; private set; }

    public IList<Products> Get(Category category)
    {
        CategoryReceived = category;
        return new List<Products>();
    }
}
```

And then test your code like this:

```
[Test]
public void PoorMansTest()
{
    // Arrange.
    var mockService = new MockService();
    var target = new ClassToTest(mockService);

    // Act.
    target.GetProducts("test");

    // Assert.
    var expectedCategory = new Category { id = "test", flag = true };
    Assert.That(mockService.CategoryReceived, Is.EqualTo(expectedCategory));
}
```